# wsl + ubuntu 20.04 access to the project loading page slow

Tags: 20.04, php, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nginx, laravel

The project environment is ubuntu 20.04 (PHP8.1 + nginx + mysql5.7 + laravel10)!
The project is runs, and found that each page load time is more than 3 seconds,
I've seen some people say that adding the

`fastcgi_buffering off`.

in the nginx configuration can improve the loading speed, but it still does not work, and I found the same problem when I use php artisan serve.
When I use `php artisan serve`, I found the same problem, can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: If you're using custom local domains, such as project.local, it may be worthwhile to double-check the local DNS settings. You'll want to have both an IPv4 and an IPv6 record pointing to the correct location. If you have *just* an IPv4, then I have seen lookups hang in the same way you describe. Adding the IPv6 record returns things to their proper speed.